# FontAwesome Pro using Libman

Tags: visual-studio-2019, font-awesome-5, libman

How can I use FontAwesome Pro using Libman in Visual Studio?

I have access to the following, cdnjs, jsdelivr and unpkg, also file system, but the latter is not ideal.

Where would I put the pro licence key? Is this even supported?

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? I'm looking to do the same thing.

Comment: Nope it seems to be impossible. The way I see it, there are 2 options, 1. as the answer stated below from Jimmy, 2. Do what I did and download the files as if you were self hosting, then use the FileSystem provider in LibMan. Downside of option 2 is that upgrading packages are not as simple as option 1 would be.

Answer (score 1):

LibMan doesn't use NPM registries directly (as it's using the CDNs mentioned in your question), so it doesn't have a way to authenticate and download the FontAwesome Pro assets.

You could use an NPM based package manager (NPM, Yarn, etc) and configure it as documented [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers) to get the FontAwesome packages, then you could use the LibMan filesystem provider to place the assets where you want them within your project.